# Fetch new posts of random user from mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I want to fetch and display posts of different users as they upload a post.. i can access their posts by userid but the posts are in sequence and not random or new posts. For example if 2 users have posted 4 times, 3 times first user and 1 time 2nd in this sequence 1st user post, 2nd user post, 1 user ,1 user, my query will return the 3 posts of user 1 first and then single post of user 2 irrelevant of the original sequence and time(old/new).

My query is

```
//this is my table -> user_post(userid,post_id,post,time) 

$query = "SELECT * FROM user_post ORDER BY (time) DESC WHERE userid = '$user_id'";
```

and i want to load only **4 latest** posts and when i next refresh the field the next 4 posts must be loaded.. 
this is a Android Client-Server Based application and i'm using `volley` to make the http calls and exchange data using JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the `limit` clause ? 
You code would be like :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_post ORDER BY (time) DESC WHERE userid = '$user_id' LIMIT 4";
```

Comment: okay i've seen this LIMIT clause but my main issue is the sequence.. i can't get the latest posts and using LIMIT in my query how i'm going to keep the record of the records that i've already used/displayed and continue to load the other records starting from next record..

Comment: SQL Query are interpreted from right to left , si if we do tht :
'$query = "SELECT * FROM user_post DESC WHERE userid = '$user_id' LIMIT 4 ORDER BY (time) ";
i think it sould do it

Answer (score -2):

You need to include a `LIMIT` clause inside your query:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM user_post ORDER BY (time) DESC WHERE userid = '$user_id' LIMIT 0,4";`

On every request you maintain a count of how many rows have loaded in `$lastLoadedRow`. The next several times you load you would do:

```
... LIMIT $lastLoadedRow,4;
... LIMIT $lastLoadedRow,4;
... LIMIT $lastLoadedRow,4;
```

Comment: and what for a dynamic database where you don't have any clue how much posts you've got.. is there any generic way to do this.. i'm afraid but hard code isn't the solution for me.

Comment: @deejay I don't understand. Could you clear up what you mean when you say "don't have any clue how much posts you've got"?

Comment: i'm making a social application where user can make infinite posts and when you load the posts from server to avoid the load on server i want to limit the num of posts to load, may be 4 at a time and when you refresh your app the next 4 posts get loaded..

Comment: @deejay That's exactly what I provided the solution for. You maintain a count of the last row you loaded. And the next time you query, your limit clause contains that count.